# Barcode scanner as a part of page Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

I want to have a **barcode scanner section in lower half of my ionic page**, currently there is a button on click of which barcode scanner UI comes up. I dont want to go another screen and get a callback. Any suggestions?

Comment: please make me clear you don't want to show barcode scanner UI from clicking button...??

Comment: Yes.. i want that whenever i open that page it should have an input field for manual entry and bottom half as scanner(pre-activated)

Comment: bar-code scanner are using camera for scan .... without scanning we can not get result so we always consider to open camera ..

Comment: I agree, i understand it, but in android native we have a surface view onto0 which we render camera, here also same thing is happening, camera is getting rendered on some view, i want to know how to control that view, 'cauz if you look closely, there is a nav-header on scanning page also. it means it is getting rendered, its not actual camera view

Comment: ok you are right .. if you get any link then comment it or i will be search this. If i got then i will give answer... @Ashwani

Comment: did you get the solution for this ?

Comment: Nopes, i am working on a plugin though for the same.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished using https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/
To add barcode scanning support you can follow https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/issues/132 I haven't done this part but the half camera and half ionic page is possible by doing the following.

```js
scanQRCode() {
    this.qrScanner.prepare().then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
      if (status.authorized) {
        this.qrScanner.show();
        this.scanning = true;
        window.document.querySelector('.app-root').classList.add('transparentBody');
        let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
          scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
          this.closeScanner(true);
          this.scanning = false;
          console.log(text);
        });
      } else if (status.denied) {
        // camera permission was permanently denied
        // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
        // then they can grant the permission from there
      } else {
        // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
      }
    }).catch((e: any) => {
      // console.log('Error is', e);
    });
}

closeScanner() {
    this.scanning = false;
    let app_root = window.document.querySelector('.app-root');
    if (app_root) {
      app_root.classList.remove('transparentBody');
    }
    this.qrScanner.hide();
    this.qrScanner.destroy();
 }
```

This will append the needed css class transparentBody to the app-root class to hide the view, and respectively bring it back. (This is placed in app.scss)

```css
.transparentBody {
   background: transparent !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Within my template I have the following

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="scanning === true">
   <div class="qrcode-container" [style.height]="'100vh'">
      <img src="assets/icon/qr-scan.svg" class="qr-code-sight"/>
      <div>
         <div>
            <button icon-only (tap)="closeScanner()">
               <ion-icon name="ios-close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

I also apply transparentBody to the page ion-content when scanning

```html
<ion-content [ngClass]="{'transparentBody': scanning}"> ... </ion-content>
```

In the end I get a QR code overlaid the camera but you could take half the height of the page and place whatever content you want there.